# User authentication doubts using JWT in front-end

Tags: authentication, security, next.js, cookies, jwt

I am currently shifted to MERN stack and implementing authentication module using Next.js (using only front-end part) + Node.js (for scalability reason).

I am using JWT token method for authentication and having below doubts:

1. Storing token in cookie can be accessible. In order to passing token in every API request we have to store token in permanent and secure place like cookie storage. but cookie is readable and rewritable using browser developer console. so how its safe?
   If me as a user using web app that has secure by jwt method then somebody can stole my token from cookie and paste it in his own machine and easily access my account.
2. Secure Route(page) issue: If I secure my routes based on cookie value and secure it like below code:

   ```
   export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
     const accessToken = req.cookies.accessToken
     if (!accessToken) {
       return {
         redirect: {
           destination: '/login',
           permanent: false,
         },
       }
     }
     return {
       props: {},
     }
   }
   ```

   then anybody can write a cookie called `accessToken` in browser console and easily access private route(pages).

   So how you prevent it?

   While working in Next.js I used to use [iron-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iron-session) where I encrypt user session details and store it to the session(Which is best way to secure user authentication process IMO).

   But how do developers and companies are using JWT in this much of volume? how to solve it?

Please give me sollution based 2 question. I studied  `{ httpOnly: true }` cookie as well but cookie is not stored and doesn't accessible, All tutorials on google and youtube are storing token in cookie and even localStorage.

And jwt is so much popular than session ? how it is more secure or better than this in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge about Node.js but in my opinion, you should not just allow pages because you found cookie in the user browser. You should implement functions that checks for example:

- who signed this token?
- when was it expected to expire?
- does it contains and verifies what you included in the token? And so on

Before you even allow accessing of page. From your script, I think you allow access when token found but you don't validate tokens before allowing access. That's the problem.

Please validate you tokens and make sure they are valid before allowing page access.

Hope this at least, reminded you something. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mac for you response!

Your point is ok to implement. but what if token stole by any user?
If any user stole my token(cookie) and paste it in his browser then all the coding scenarios will match and thief user can access my account (in app) easily

Comment: Listen, you don't have to dwell only on jwt. You could still use together with sessions. JWT doesn't guarantee you from not using sessions.

Comment: If what in the JWT doesn't match the session data variable, then you catch an attacker. Lemme know if you still need more help

Comment: Okay, do you have any resource that explain jwt + session implementation?

Comment: Don't know if you gonna find this helpful. See https://nonepress.com/overflow/42/how-to-securely-save-jwt-in-frontend?show=43#a43 for some answer/s